# Hooking up two sender actions from a background tap and an Enter

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Ok so I have this following screen

[image: user creation page]

I have the "Did End On Exit" and "Editing Did End" events connected to every UITextField IBOutlet and the events are connected to a method called **userDoneEditing**, also I have A UITapGestureRecognizer that has **@selector(dismissKeyboard)**
Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _userFirstNameEntry = UserFirstName.text;
    _userLastNameEntry = UserLastName.text;
    _emailEntry = UserEmail.text;
    _userEntry = UserUser.text;
    _userPasswordEntry = UserPassword.text;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(360, 760))];
    //initilizing UITapGestureRecognizer referenced by *tap
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (IBAction)userDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    if(sender == UserFirstName)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserFirstName did end editing");
    }
    else if(sender == UserLastName)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserLastName did end editing");
    }
    else if(sender == UserEmail)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserEmail did end editing");
    }
    else if(sender == UserUser)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserUser did end editing");
    }
    else if(sender == UserPassword)
    {
        NSLog(@"textField *UserPassword did end editing");
    }
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [UserFirstName resignFirstResponder];
    [UserLastName resignFirstResponder];
    [UserEmail resignFirstResponder];
    [UserUser resignFirstResponder];
    [UserPassword resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

The Problem: 
I just need my dismissKeyboard method to recognize the sender, so that I may qualify sender-specified actions, how can I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol to assist with keeping track of what's going on with your UITextField objects.

In your headers interface add the protocol  and in your viewDidLoad assign each UITextField a delegate.

Example:

```
UserFirstName.delegate = self;
```

All protocol methods for UITextFieldDelegate are optional, however you most likely will need textFieldDidBeginEditing: , textFieldDidEndEditing: and textFieldShouldReturn:

Each of these methods are handed the UITextField that called the method, so you can keep track of first responder changes, update instance variables and make decisions.

In your dismissKeyboard method you could then check the state of these instance variables.

Comment: right, I have read the docs for UITextField Delegate Protocol, but I guess what I'm still confused about is.. Does it have to specifically be the textFieldDoneEditing, etc. methods in order to recognize the delegates? @Bamsworld

Comment: Yes you really do, Mr Bam is spot on the money..

there are a number of control devices in UIKit that you'll really struggle to get full function from without implementing their built in protocols, (UITableView, UIPickerView, UITextField etc) its a very common design pattern with Apple.

Essentially your text fields need an object to talk to, 'hey things have changed here...' ..'user wants to type in me is this ok?'.. 'user thinks he's finished typing in me, shall i let him finish?' etc..

you don't necessarily need to put this protocol in your view controller, it may be in a helper class etc.